# how to implement a handler for a second click on a li of a different ul in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

At the begging I have one ul:

```
<div id="ul1DivId">
    <ul id="ul1Id">
        <li>li1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Than I have a javascript that will hide this div/ul and add another div with another ul:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ul1Id > li").click(function() {
                    //to prevent scroll firing this handler:
        event.preventDefault();

        $("#ul1DivId").hide();
        var someValue = "someValue";
        var outputUl2Html = "<div id=\"ul2DivId\">" +
        "<ul id=\"ul2Id\">" +
        "<li id=\"liXId\">> " + someValue + "</li>" +
        "<li id=\"clearLiId\">-clear-</li>" +
        "</ul>" +
        "</div>";
        //show ul 2
        $(outputUl2Html).insertAfter('#ul1DivId');

});
});
```

Than I get `style="display: none; "` in the div with `id="ul1DivId"`. This is expected. And I get the new inserted div after the hidden div element. This is expected too.

I have another javascript that never gets fired when clicking `clearLiId`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clearLiId").click(function() {
        //I never reach here!!!!
    });
});
```

I tried also `#ul2Id > li` and `#ul2Id > #clearLiId` as selectors. Nothing gets the handler fired when I click on the `#clearLiId` `li`! Why? How do I get it to catch the click event? I want to show the first div (`ul1DivId`) again and remove the current div (`ul2DivId`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `event` arguments and you need delegate event like following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#clearLiId', function() {
     //I never reach here!!!!
});


$("#ul1Id > li").click(function(event) {...
                                 ^ ----- missing event
```

---

#### Note

I seems though `$("#ul1Id > li").` is working for your first `ul` but it will not working for future coming `ul`s. So it would be better if you assign `class` to each `ul`(already in DOM and will come in future) and change your selector. For example:

***HTML***

```
<div id="ul1DivId">
    <ul id="ul1Id" class="someClassToUl">
        <li>li1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

***jQuery***

```
$(".someClassToUl > li")...
```

Comment: I don't get what u mean by "future coming ul s", but $("#ul1Id > li").click(function() { works well even without the event part. thanks for the on solution though!

Comment: @despot that means `ul` coming to DOM after page load. But feeling happy to know that works.

Comment: Actually the function(event) part is required for ff. I was looking only in chrome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `live()` function because the selector does not exist yet.

> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clearLiId").live(function() {
        //I never reach here!!!!
    });
});
```

Comment: Note `live()` has been deprecated and replaced by `on()`